# How can i hide dt if dd got empty value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I need to hide dt if dd got empty value. how can i do that?

```
  <dt class="col-sm-6 text-dark"  >Subject</dt>
   <dd class="col-sm-6">{{$course_dtl->subject_title }}</dd>
```

Like i want to hide Subject  if subject_title has no value.

Comment: Hide it via javascript or just not render it? Blade has [If Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#if-statements)

Answer (score 2):

As Brombeer said blade templating has if statements and you can surround the whole block with one:

```php
@if (!empty($course_dtl->subject_title))
   <dt class="col-sm-6 text-dark"  >Subject</dt>
   <dd class="col-sm-6">{{$course_dtl->subject_title }}</dd>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide only **dt** then you can do this also

```
<dt class="col-sm-6 text-dark" style="display: {{ $course_dtl->subject_title ? 'block' : 'none' }}" >Subject</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-6">{{$course_dtl->subject_title }}</dd>
```